# NunitLite Logging info for each test to the console

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I'm creating some Integration tests with NUnit, and I'm using NUnitLite to run them as a console app. But the annoying thing is, what once I'll run them, they'll be just hanging without any information on about what kind of test has been done at the moment, on what exactly the runner works curently. Just I need to wait some time and after that the result comes: X passed, Y failed, Z errors.

Is there a possibility to change that somehow? In order to have a shortcut info on which tests has been done already, with what result, and log that info for each Test method in my project?

Answer (score 1):

The `--labels` option will give you some of what you want, running, for example

```
MyTest.exe --labels=After
```

The following values may be used with the option:

- Off - No labels are displayed for tests. This is the default if `--labels` is not used.
- On - Displays labels for any tests that that produce output. This is the default if you use `--labels` alone.
- Before - Displays a label when the test begins, whether it produces output or not.
- All - Same as Before. (Yes, this is odd. It's for backward compatibility.)
- After - Displays a label when the test finishes, showing whether it passed.

Unfortunately, NUnitLite does not have the option `labels=BeforeAndAfter`, which is available in the console runner. That would solve both your concerns: what is currently running and what has completed. With NUnitLite you must choose between Before and After.

I suggest using After most of the time, but switching to Before if you need to identify a test that is hanging.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I looked for that info on how to use labels :)